# Crack the Lost Numbers

Tags: arithmetic, atomic-code-golf

The Lost Numbers are 4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42. Your goal is to create an expression to output them all.

Your allowed characters are 0123456789, ^+-*/, (), % for modulo and n as the single variable allowed. Modified PEMDAS `()^*/%+-` is the precedence and / is normal division (3/2 = 1.5). 0^0 = 1 although division by 0 is undefined.

Create the shortest expression (in characters) such that for n = 0..5 (or 1..6 for 1-indexing) the nth Lost Number will be the result of the expression. Shortest expression wins.

Comment: What if the language can't handle the size of the number :P?

Comment: [Relevant OEIS](https://oeis.org/A104101)

Comment: What's the precedence of the operators? (e.g. does `17%4*3` evaluate as `3` or `5`?)

Comment: Parentheses Exponents Multiply Divide Add Subtract

Comment: What about the modulo?

Comment: Can we substitute `^+-*/%` if our language uses different characters for those operations?

Comment: As this is atomic code golf you're supposed to only use the idealized language described in the challenge (it can handle unbounded ints too).

Comment: Ah, my bad. I didn't see that. Or know what that was. Sounds fun!

Comment: @Arnauld edited post to clarify precedence

Comment: Is `/` division or integer division? (Does `3/2` evaluate as `1` or `1.5`?)

Comment: @RobinRyder normal division

Comment: So 3-3+4 is -4 (since + is higher precedence)?

Comment: Yes (filler text)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## 15 bytes

```julia
n*4+703%n^3%7*3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUz8n5ZfpJBna2hlxlVQlJlXkpOn8T9Py0Tb3MBYNS/OWNVcy/i/JldqXsp/AA)

Based off @Arnauld's answer.

The idea was to look for a magic formula `A%n^B%C` that maps (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) to (0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 6) to combine the last two terms in Arnauld's formula into one:

```julia
 n           |  1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |  5 |  6 | (x4)
 703%n^3%7   |  0 |  0 |  1 |  0 |  1 |  6 | (x3)
-------------+----+----+----+----+----+----+------
             |  4 |  8 | 15 | 16 | 23 | 42 |
```

Answer (score 9):

## 20 characters

Assuming that the precedence of the operators is similar to JS. The input is expected to be 1-indexed.

```javascript
n*4+16%n*3+6*0^(6-n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcxBCsMgEEDRvaeYTYmj0VRa3LS5SQkRa0OKjEFLNiFnt64@b/O/bnfF53X7KUrvUAuMMFcSd2nshcRNWnGduFWEddYlrj5w04MyqHPYomscXtOw9NAJ0SFjn5Q5tYd5AMFzBNsqJcLBAHyikmLQMS087C7ygsjO@gc) (interpreted in JS ES7)

#### Breakdown

```
 n           |  1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |  5 |  6 | (x4)
 16 % n      |  0 |  0 |  1 |  0 |  1 |  4 | (x3)
 0 ^ (6 - n) |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  1 | (x6)
-------------+----+----+----+----+----+----+------
             |  4 |  8 | 15 | 16 | 23 | 42 |
```

Comment: Brilliant! It looks like `n*4+16%n*8%13%7*3` works.

Comment: @Lynn This is clearly pushing it a step further, so feel free to post it as a new answer.

Answer (score 9):

## <del>16</del> 15 characters

`6704196%(n*8+3)`

One-indexed. A simple application of a generalisation of the Chinese Remainder Theorem, with the formula n*8+3 chosen to make it work (that is, where moduli have a common factor, the corresponding values' difference is also divisible by that factor), as well as to get a shorter number on the left.

Previously: `485559068%(n+41)`, zero-indexed

Comment: Have you tried expressions of the form `a%(b-n)`?

Comment: @Neil I just tried that, and found nothing better than the original from it.